# Is there a Stack Exchange site for Meta (Facebook) business account related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am getting an error when trying to do some action in a [Meta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Platforms) (Facebook) business account regarding adding my [WhatsApp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp) account to the business account.

I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask about this specific question.

I didn't find a solution to the error from Google, and I didn't find a community/forum where I can ask.

Is there a Stack Overflow type site for "Meta business accounts" questions?

Comment: Welcome to [meta.se]. What is textual error?

Comment: The link to the "duplicated question" is about user accounts, while this question is about "business accounts" which probably means the question is asking about advertising, boosting message, or business use of social media. I mention this because I'm interested in the latter, but on quick examination there seems to be no stack exchange site for it.

Answer (score 17):

There isn’t any site on the Stack Exchange Network for customer service questions / support tickets questions (stuff that only company agents might answer).

The [SE technology list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) has several sites that might be somehow related. Few of them allow troubleshooting questions, but they should be focused on stuff that is on-topic, i.e., [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) allows some troubleshooting questions regarding using computers as end-users, but not about web services, like Facebook, on the other hand on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) questions about web applications like https://web.whatsapp.com are on-topic, but troubleshooting questions aren't.

If the error is related to the web browser that you are using, your computer operative system or utilities ([VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), antivirus, etc.) the question might be on-topic on Super User.

If the error occurs on a mobile device and it's related to the mobile hardware, software or its settings it might on-topic on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) (Apple) or [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).

If the error is related a misunderstanding on the web page instructions / concepts about how to link the accounts it might be on-topic on Web Applications.

If the problem is on the Meta / Facebook side, the question is off-topic on SE.

**Related**

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)
- [On which Stack Exchange site can I ask customer service questions about product X or company Y?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347991/289691)
- [Where to ask "WhatsApp says I am being 'rate limited'"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385767/289691)